# MapView v2 keeping Context around

Tags: android, google-maps, memory-leaks, android-mapview, leakcanary

When using the MapView from the latest google maps API, I am getting a memory leak because MapView is holding onto my activity.

I used Leak Canary and have this trace

---

D/LeakCanary﹕ * GC ROOT com.google.android.gms.location.internal.t.a

D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.google.android.gms.location.internal.s.a

D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.v.c

D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.aj.b

D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.p.a

D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.mParent

D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.widget.FrameLayout.mParent

D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.mContext

D/LeakCanary﹕ * leaks com.myapp.activities.main.AttractionDetailActivity instance

---

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Known issue.  If enough people star it, maybe it'll get fixed before 2018: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8111

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check if you are calling `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` in your onMapReady() callback.

If you are then you should call `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false)` in your onDestroy.

Comment: Actually this worked... Still I think is a bug that should be fixed but thank you!

Comment: I'm still seeing the leak occur even when applying this workaround.

Comment: @NasaGeek Guess this is too late but can confirm whether the leak the same as this or something else. Google Maps SDK has many leaks, I guess most of them have been fixed in the latest version of google play services

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            mMap.clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just to give another option as this solution didn't work for me.

I found this really useful thread where it propose some workarounds related to the memory leak in MapView:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/issues/26

For me, the most interesting things from this thread (that worked for me) is:

> 1) Make sure to unregister your callbacks:

```
if (googleApiClient != null) {
        googleApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
        googleApiClient.unregisterConnectionFailedListener(this);

        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
        }

        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        googleApiClient = null;
 }
```

> 2) Use a WeakReference for LocationListener

```
public class WeakLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    private final WeakReference<LocationListener> locationListenerRef;

    public WeakLocationListener(@NonNull LocationListener locationListener) {
        locationListenerRef = new WeakReference<>(locationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
        if (locationListenerRef.get() == null) {
            return;
        }
        locationListenerRef.get().onLocationChanged(location);
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!